# replace missing value with n-1

Tags: python, pandas

for example :  I have,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [420, np.nan, 455, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})

df

       0
0  420.0
1    NaN
2  455.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
5    NaN
```

then using :

```
df[0].isnull().astype(int)

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

I get

```
df[0].fillna(method='ffill') - df[0].isnull().astype(int)

0    420.0
1    419.0
2    455.0
3    454.0
4    454.0
5    454.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I am looking for to get  0,1,0,1,2,3, then in the end :

> df[0]= 420, 419, 455; 454,453, 452

Answer (score 4):

#### `groupby`, `cumcount`

```
df[0].ffill() - df.groupby(df[0].notna().cumsum()).cumcount()

0    420.0
1    419.0
2    455.0
3    454.0
4    453.0
5    452.0
dtype: float64
```

---

#### Details

Define groups

```
df[0].notna().cumsum()

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Use in `groupby` with `cumcount`

```
df.groupby(df[0].notna().cumsum()).cumcount()

0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can using `cumsum` as well

```
s=df[0].isnull().astype(int).groupby(df[0].notnull().cumsum()).cumsum()
s
Out[430]: 
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    2
5    3
Name: 0, dtype: int32

#df[0].ffill() - s
```